# SOLVED:What else to set on vps linux server to allow https for spring boot

Tags: linux, spring-boot, https, certificate, vps

I am running spring-boot jar application on VPS virtual server (ubuntu) and I am facing certificate_unknown issue. I have tried almost everything but no success.

1. When I run jar (spring-boot) with http profile, and hosting as well in http mode then is able all works. So I know that connection is correct
2. When I call spring-boot on vps from postmen using https address, then is works as well.
3. Last when hosting now in https mode calls spring-boot running with server.ssl.enabled=true then in log I have error =>
   `onUncaughtException(SimpleConnection{channel=[id: 0x4e6d10c4 ..... Caused by:  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: **Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown`**

I have trusted certificate from domain, I also have intermediate certificate. Both imported in my keystore-certificate.p12 file that is addressed from

```
application.properties like this
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=/root/myfolder/keystore-certificate.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=keystore-password
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

Intermediate certificate is imported as first, domain certificate as second. Certificate is valid, I have checked that so I have no idea what can cause issues. Hosting has correctly set up https protocol so I can see certificate details from icon in url. When I send request from hosting, then this is in header

```
Accept:
application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer:
https://dev-environment.hosting.fun/

Request URL:
https://ipaddress:8080/
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

On vps there is port allowed for 8080 i have checked that, I have also added permissions to

> Blockquote

keystore-certificate.p12

> Blockquote

to be sure that spring-boot is able to read content.

For getting certificate I used -

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns -d hosting.fun -d dev- 
environment.hosting.fun
```

,then converted it to pk12 file and then imported into keystore-certificate.p12.

What else am I missing?

Comment: when i run this check -> root@ubuntu:~/myfolder# openssl x509 -in keystore-certificate.p12 -noout -subject
Enter pass phrase for PKCS12 import pass phrase:
subject=CN = hosting.fun <- result but I dont see my subdomain from which I am making call dev-environment.hosting.fun so this is probably that issue

Comment: Didnot help. I moved content from dev-environment.hosting.fun to hosting.fun so that CN is really the same but no change. Do I have to allow anything on vps? I think that port for https doesnt need to be allowed when I use only port 8080. So maybe temporary turn off firewall on vps?

Answer (score 0):

So in case anybody will not have so much experience like me this solved my problem.

I was calling ip address which is not allowed for https where in certificate you dont have ip address but CN = common name of hosting or also other names if you add them.

So you need to set up DNS record on you hosting, where you will add ip address of you remote server you are trying to call and name, that will reflect name from certificate. So then, your angular or what ever application will not call https://ipaddress but https://dev-hosting.com for example.